# Bias-corrected percentile Bootstrapping Optimization

Tags: beginner, time-limit-exceeded, statistics, r

I have never posted to this forum, but was referred here. I need some help printing key iterations as well as optimizing my code for run time. If someone had some time to help/explain how to correct various parts, I would be much obliged. I am fairly new to R and trying to help out on a project.

I am trying to run a bias-corrected percentile bootstrap for 3 different effect sizes. I heavily modified code from a colleague on a zero-truncated Poisson distribution to include bootstrapping for percentiles. While this code functions, the run time takes FAR too long. It takes about 3 days to do all of the 3 different effect sizes. At the end of the run, it only produces the last results for the last line and not anything in between. This is the real problem as I have the time.

The console shows each of the 1000 iterations running which I do not need. Ideally, I would like to optimize run time. I would also like all  of the outputs on the console or into a word/excel document rather than having to run them one at time. I would like for it to print the power of ab1, power of ab2, type I error of ab1 and type I error of ab2 for each of the seeds in each effect. Ideally, I would those 4 metrics broken down by effect and then again by seed within the effect. All these gathered in one place.

I know the code is a bit clunky, and some help would be appreciated.

I am fairly new to R, and was looking for some advice on how to proceed appropriately. The code is presented below:

```
library(pscl)
library(boot)

# RNG MODULE FOR TWO_PART HURDLE MODEL

gen.hurdle = function(n, a, b1, b2, c1, c2, i0, i1, i2){

  x = round(rnorm(n),3)
  e = rnorm(n)
  m = round(i0 + a*x + e, 3)

  lambda = exp(i1 + b1*m + c1*x)                       # PUT REGRESSION TERMS FOR THE CONTINUUM PART HERE; KEEP exp()
  ystar = qpois(runif(n, dpois(0, lambda), 1), lambda) # Zero-TRUNCATED POISSON DIST.; THE CONTINUUM PART

  z = i2 + b2*m  + c2*x                                # PUT REGRESSION TERMS FOR THE BINARY    PART HERE
  z_p = exp(z) / (1+exp(z))                            # p(1) = 1-p(0)
  tstar = rbinom(n, 1, z_p)                            # BINOMIAL DIST.         ; THE BINARY    PART

  y= ystar*tstar                                       # TWO-PART COUNT OUTCOME

  return(cbind(x,m,y,z,z_p,tstar))
}


##################################################################################################
# MODEL ##########################################################################################
##################################################################################################

# i=1  ###################################

#small effect
seed=51; n=50  ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1
seed=53; n=100 ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1
seed=55; n=200 ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1
seed=57; n=300 ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1
seed=58; n=500 ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1
seed=59; n=1000;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1

#medium effect
seed=61; n=50  ;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1
seed=63; n=100 ;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1
seed=65; n=200 ;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1
seed=67; n=300 ;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1
seed=68; n=500 ;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1
seed=69; n=1000;a=.31; b=.35; c=.25; i=1

#large effect
seed=81; n=50  ;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1
seed=73; n=100 ;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1
seed=75; n=200 ;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1
seed=77; n=300 ;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1
seed=78; n=500 ;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1
seed=79; n=1000;a=.52; b=.49; c=.25; i=1


#model
set.seed(seed)
iterations = 1000
r = 1000

results = matrix(,iterations,4)
for (iiii in 1:iterations){

  data  = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, b, b, c, c, i, i, i))
  data0 = data.frame(gen.hurdle(n, a, 0, 0, c, c, i, i, i))

  p_0     =1-mean(data$z_p)
  p_0_hat =1-mean(data$tstar)
  p_0_b0     =1-mean(data0$z_p)
  p_0_hat_b0 =1-mean(data0$tstar)

  # power

  boot= matrix(,r,8)
  for(jjjj in 1:r){

    #power
    fit1      = lm(m ~ x, data=data)
    fit2      = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial") 

    a_hat     = summary(fit1)$coef[2,1]
    b1_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$count[2,1]
    b2_hat    = summary(fit2)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
    ab1_hat   = prod(a_hat,b1_hat)
    ab2_hat   = prod(a_hat,b2_hat)

    boot.data = data[sample(nrow(data), replace = TRUE), ]
    boot.data$y[1] = if(prod(boot.data$y) > 0) 0 else boot.data$y[1]

    boot.fit1 = lm(m ~ x, data=boot.data)
    boot.fit2 = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=boot.data, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial") 

    boot.a    = summary(boot.fit1)$coef[2,1]
    boot.b1   = summary(boot.fit2)[[1]]$count[2,1]
    boot.b2   = summary(boot.fit2)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
    boot.ab1  = prod(boot.a,boot.b1)
    boot.ab2  = prod(boot.a,boot.b2)

    #type I error
    fit3       = lm(m ~ x, data=data0)
    fit4       = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=data0, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")  

    a_hat_b0   = summary(fit3)$coef[2,1]
    b1_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$count[2,1]
    b2_hat_b0  = summary(fit4)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
    ab1_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b1_hat_b0)
    ab2_hat_b0 = prod(a_hat_b0,b2_hat_b0)

    boot.data0 = data0[sample(nrow(data0), replace = TRUE), ]
    boot.data0$y[1] = if(prod(boot.data0$y) > 0) 0 else boot.data0$y[1]

    boot.fit3  = lm(m ~ x, data=boot.data0)
    boot.fit4  = hurdle(formula = y ~ m + x, data=boot.data0, dist = "poisson", zero.dist = "binomial")  

    boot.a_b0   = summary(boot.fit3)$coef[2,1]
    boot.b1_b0  = summary(boot.fit4)[[1]]$count[2,1]
    boot.b2_b0  = summary(boot.fit4)[[1]]$zero[2,1]
    boot.ab1_b0 = prod(boot.a_b0,boot.b1_b0)
    boot.ab2_b0 = prod(boot.a_b0,boot.b2_b0)

    boot[jjjj,] = c(ab1_hat,    ab2_hat,    boot.ab1,    boot.ab2,
                    ab1_hat_b0, ab2_hat_b0, boot.ab1_b0, boot.ab2_b0)

  }

  z0.1 = qnorm((sum(boot[,3] > boot[,1])+sum(boot[,3]==boot[,1])/2)/r)
  z0.2 = qnorm((sum(boot[,4] > boot[,2])+sum(boot[,4]==boot[,2])/2)/r)
  z0.1_b0 = qnorm((sum(boot[,7] > boot[,5])+sum(boot[,7]==boot[,5])/2)/r)
  z0.2_b0 = qnorm((sum(boot[,8] > boot[,6])+sum(boot[,8]==boot[,6])/2)/r)

  alpha=0.05 # 95% limits
  z=qnorm(c(alpha/2,1-alpha/2)) # Std. norm. limits

  p1    = pnorm(z-2*z0.1) # bias-correct & convert to proportions
  p2    = pnorm(z-2*z0.2) 
  p1_b0 = pnorm(z-2*z0.1_b0)
  p2_b0 = pnorm(z-2*z0.2_b0) 

  ci1    = quantile(boot[,3],p=p1) # Bias-corrected percentile lims
  ci2    = quantile(boot[,4],p=p2)
  ci1_b0 = quantile(boot[,7],p=p1_b0)
  ci2_b0 = quantile(boot[,8],p=p2_b0)

  sig.ab1 = if(prod(ci1) > 0) 1 else 0
  sig.ab2 = if(prod(ci2) > 0) 1 else 0
  sig.ab1_b0 = if(prod(ci1_b0) > 0) 1 else 0
  sig.ab2_b0 = if(prod(ci2_b0) > 0) 1 else 0



  #results
  results[iiii,] = c(sig.ab1, sig.ab2, sig.ab1_b0, sig.ab2_b0)

  message(paste0(iiii, " / iterations"))
  flush.console()
}

i
n
a
b
iterations
#bootstrap how many
r

#power of ab1
mean(results[,1])
#power of ab2
mean(results[,2])
#type I error of ab1
mean(results[,3])
#type I error of ab2
mean(results[,4])
```

It would seem to me that the problem with each of the effects being ran separately is coming from naming the results "results" for each loop. I do not know the best way to print each metric(for each effect size) without disturbing the loop. Alternatively, I could aggregate them into one chart as mentioned before.

The length is obviously coming from the sheer amount of iterations and lack of RAM to process them fast enough. Is this something that can even been remedied? The time isn't nearly as much of a concern as not getting results for all effect sizes when the program is run.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have to be the author of the code to get it reviewed. You can read more about that in the Help Center at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AlexV Hi! Thank you for pointing out that rule breach. I made some major changes to the code as it originally was just code for zero-truncated poisson distribution which I modified for bootstrapping. Is this permissible? I can reflect that in the message.

Comment: I personally would consider your question valid under these circumstances. You should definitely reflect that in your question!

Comment: In a nutshell, the code is executed from top to bottom, so of all the lines looking like `seed=51; n=50  ;a=.18; b=.16; c=.25; i=1` will be immediately overridden by the one below and only the values in the last such line will enter the double `for` loop model. You need to write a function that takes `seed`, `n`, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `i` as inputs.

Comment: @flodel Thank you! I suspected as much. I think it may even be refitting the same data 1000 times for each of the 1000 data sets randomly generated from the 1 seed (the last one since there's nothing looping through the list)